# Is uops.info wrong about vinserti128?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, simd, avx2

According to uops.info, the reciprocal throughput of `vinserti128` is 0.5 if the xmm argument comes from memory, and 1 if the xmm argument is a register. What's the underlying reason behind this? Is it a mistake? [Link](https://uops.info/table.html?search=vinserti128&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_SKX=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_doc=on&cb_base=on&cb_avx=on&cb_avx2=on)

I don't understand why ports 0 and 1 are only an option if the xmm argument is *not* a register. Is there something in hardware that can explain this?

[image]

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer on that, but you can say that `vinserti128` with a memory-source behaves like a blend, whereas with a register source it behaves like a shuffle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Uops.info automated testing doesn't have typos

If there's anything surprising, it's either a real effect or an artifact of exactly how they tested.  You can click on any number to see the detailed test results including the instruction sequences used to test throughput and ports.  In this case, yes, the memory-source version is different, and the test results make sense.

As chtz commented, the register-source version works like a shuffle, but the memory-source version is probably decoding as a **broadcast-load + blend**.

---

We know that **Intel load ports can broadcast to 256-bit for free since Haswell (4, 8, or 16-byte chunks)**.  `vbroadcastss/d` / `vpbroadcastd/q` are single-uop, so are `vbroadcasti128` / `vbroadcastf128`.  Even `vmovddup ymm, [mem]` is a single load-port uop on Intel (port 2 or 3), no ALU required for duplicating the low half of each 16-byte lane.   (Filter on `vbroadcast ymm` in https://uops.info/)

---

For the blend part, Haswell and later could reuse the `vpblendd` execution unit by constructing a control operand for it from the `vinserti128` immediate.  That's a single uop for any vector ALU port (p015).

To avoid bypass latency, `vinsertf128` could similarly use a `vblendps` or `pd` execution unit.

---

Sandy/Ivy Bridge could only broadcast for free to 128-bit XMM; it needed a port5 shuffle for `vbroadcastss/sd/f128 ymm, mem` (and didn't have register-source broadcasts; those were new in AVX2).  But it ran `vinserti/f128 mem` as `1*p05 + 1*p23` vs `p5` for register-source `vinsert` or `vperm2f128`.

SnB/IvB CPUs ran `vblendps`/`pd` on `p05`, so presumably `vinsertf128` from memory is using the FP blend units on those ports.  (It wasn't until Haswell that port 1 could also run `vblendps`.)

So presumably it had some special support for forwarding a 128-bit load result to either the low or high lane of an execution unit that could do the merging.  (Perhaps with the blend units designed to accept that?)

If it could forward to both lanes, I'd have assumed it could do that in general, and wouldn't have needed a port 5 uop for `vbroadcastf128 ymm, mem` on top of the load uop.  Unless it's relevant that the intermediate broadcast result never needs to be architecturally visible (written to a hard YMM register), potentially persisting indefinitely if the register isn't written for a long time.  But combined with the blend control input generated from the immediate, the input can be a bit funky and only the output needs to be fully normal and potentially part of a persistent state.